# Automatically Check all ListBox options when opening a UserForm

Tags: vba, userform

I have a ListBox called ListBox1 and I want to select all of the values automatically when opening the form. How can I do this?

My ListBox looks something like this

[image]

Comment: What application are you using for the Userform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use For Loop and embed it in userform initialise event.....

```
For i = 0 To MyListBox1.ListCount - 1 
    MyListBox1.Selected(i) = True
Next i
```

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either in your script set all of the checkboxes to true with this piece of code that will loop over all of your different controls and set the checkbox ones to true

```
Dim currentControl As Control

For Each currentControl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf currentControl Is msforms.CheckBox Then
        currentControl.Value = SelectAllCheckBox.Value
    End If
Next
```

or you can put this code in a button called 'Select All' that will on click select all of the checkboxes.

Comment: This will check single CheckBoxes, but OP asks to select all items of a ListBox.